# How to collaborate to a Firebase project with not google account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an invitation from the firebase project but can't activate it cause the mail I was invited with is outlook (not a google account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Google account from any email address, not just for @gmail.com. See the Google documentation page on [creating a Google account from an existing email address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?existingemail). Once you've followed that process, you can sign in to the Firebase project with the account.